# How to calculate the best value for shuffle partition in Spark DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I calculate the trade off between number of partitions and size of `DataFrame` in Spark whit `spark.conf.set` configuration?

Comment: By value of shuffle partition, you mean "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" ?